# Installing Visual Studio Express 2010

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

I would like to create some test web applications with [Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#History).

I installed Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express, but I can't choose the "ASP.NET MVC 2" type of project web application.

What should I install if I want to create a web ASP.NET MVC 2 application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's necessary to install [Visual Web Developer 2010 Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_Web_Developer_Express).

Answer (score 3):

I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and I see it. The following is what I do:

File > New Project

Then under the Web template you will find ASP.Net MVC 2 Web Application

You will NOT find it under File > Web Site, which I am assuming you might be looking at.

Comment: Appears that if i want to use visual studio express, i have to install visual web developer 2010 express instead visual studio 2010 express

Comment: @Josemalive You are correct, you do need Visual Studio Web Developer Express, I had it open too when I was posting my answer, but in my haste typed the wrong name. You should post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

That's a separate (free) install.  [See here](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Install link is top-right on the page.

Comment: Appears that if i want to use visual studio express, i have to install visual web developer 2010 express instead visual studio 2010 express